# How could I implement Date-Time calculations in JSP?

Tags: jsp

How could i implement date calculations in JSP?

1.entering date

2.adding hours,minutes,days to a date

3.recognizing the day of a date

Answer (score 0):

Parse it with a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` then convert it to a `java.util.Calendar` which supports things like adding time and extracting fields like the day of the week.